# Add a margin for all images without link inside a post content

Tags: css, image, margin

I would like to add a margin for all images **without link** inside a post content .

```
.post-content img (here I need to target only the images whith no link) {
margin: 1em;
}
```

All images with a link must keep its own margin.

Do you please have a CSS or even javascript solution?

Cheers

Comment: How do your images have links? I assume they're just wrapped in an `<a>` tag? In this case, `.post-content img` will only target the images without links. If there's JavaScript, you won't be able to do much. It would help if you could update your question to list **all** relevant code in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your HTML is generated server-side, could you please post the **output**. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) :)

Comment: add your `HTML` code.

Comment: If you're talking about the `src`attribute then it is required (HTML5 specifications), so I don't understand this question at all

Comment: You're right, I am not asking the right question. I need to add a margin for all images which are contains inside <a href=".." ...> <img> </a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `<img>` is child of `<div class="post-content">` you can use this code.

```
.post-content > img {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

Because img is in the first level of children.

But if you have other wrappers, you can use this code to add margin to images without link, and then reset the margin of images with link.

```
.post-content img {
  margin: 1em;
}

.post-content a > img {
  margin: 0; /* Or the original margin */
}
```

Comment: You absolutely got it! Thanks Joan